# Sitecore Could not find configuration node dataAdapterManager

Tags: c#, razor, sitecore

Getting error "**Could not find configuration node: dataAdapterManager**" when i Using below line of code to get the top most visited page in Sitecore :-

```
string query =
        string.Format(
            "SELECT TOP {0} ItemId, count(*) as cnt FROM Pages WHERE DateTime > DATEADD(DAY, -{1}, GETDATE()) GROUP BY ItemId ORDER BY cnt DESC",
            10, 90);

    IEnumerable<Guid> itemIDs = DataAdapterManager.Sql.ReadMany(query,
        reader => new
        {
            ItemId =DataAdapterManager.Sql.GetGuid(0, reader),
        },
        new object[0]).Select(a => a.ItemId);

    IEnumerable<Item> popularPages= itemIDs.Select(id => Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ID(id))).Where(item => item != null).ToList();

    foreach(var pp in popularPages)
    {


        Response.Write(pp.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing DMS package.

This url help me to solve the issue.

First Download the DMS package from sitecore website then follwo the given instructions.

http://www.nehemiahj.com/2011/12/sitecore-dms-installation.html